# Can I replace existing duplicate files on macOS APFS filesystems with clones?

Tags: macos, filesystem, apfs

When you copy a file on APFS, it doesn't actually duplicate the file blocks, instead it just clones the metadata. This is known as copy on write (COW). That prevents identical files from using any more space until you make an edit to the duplicate file, and then , only the changed blocks take up space so substantially identical files share most of their storage in common even after a change.

I'm hoping there is some tool to find existing duplicates and replace them with clones, reclaiming the space used to store the duplicate.

My research shows questions on [Apple Communities](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8096756) and the [MacRumors Forums](https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/hfs-to-apfs-deduplicate-existing-files.2051751/) don't propose any solutions.

Is there a way to use the copy-on-write cloning feature of APFS to reclaim space from existing duplicate files?

Comment: Hard to believe that nobody wrote an app to do this yet. On my home folder alone, there's 4.41 GB to be saved from doing this. That's far from a negligible amount. Take note: app developers, I'd gladly pay a few dollars for this!

Answer (score 12):

As of June 2020, [Jdupes](https://github.com/jbruchon/jdupes) can do this.

For example, this will find all duplicates in your Applications folder:

```
jdupes --recurse --dedupe /Applications/
```

**WARNING:** Versions before [1.19.0](https://github.com/jbruchon/jdupes/releases/tag/v1.19.0) will [overwrite metadata (date, owner, permission)](https://github.com/jbruchon/jdupes/issues/142), more recent versions preserve all metadata when using `jdupes --dedupe` on APFS filesystems.

Comment: metadata is declared fixed in 1.19.0

Comment: This is incredible and almost certainly will work on iOS jailbroken APFS devices too (iOS 10.3+). I'm going to compile jdupes on my iPad and see if I can dedupe!

Comment: Update: jdupes 1.19 and 1.20 compile perfectly on my iOS 12.4 and 13.3 jailbroken systems using clang 10 and iOS SDK 12.4 and 13.4. The APFS clonefile(2) CoW dedupe is incredible!!! Test files I experimented with have worked great. I stand to gain at least 10GB on my (full) 256GB iPad Pro from deduping, but I'm still testing to gain more confidence before I turn jdupes loose on my entire disk.

Comment: jdupes 1.2.0 can corrupt files having APFS compression - https://github.com/jbruchon/jdupes/issues/189

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem and wrote a [small shell script](https://gist.github.com/tvwerkhoven/9a30c6adc7f95a0278e895b5563b900b) to do this using native `cp`, `mv`, `jdupes` (for speed), and `gcp` (for metadata preservation). Hope this helps!

Advantage over other solutions:

- http://diskdedupe.com and https://macpaw.com/gemini: Free, open-source, use byte-wise comparison to prevent collisions
- https://github.com/deckarep/apfs-compactor & https://bitbucket.org/dchevell/apfs-deduplicate: Preserve metadata, use byte-wise comparison to prevent collisions
- https://github.com/ranvel/clonefile-dedup: No SQL/Python dependencies, use byte-wise comparison to prevent collisions

Comment: How do you use this script? Is there documentation somewhere?

Comment: `jdupes` now supports APFS `clonefile()` natively as of v1.17.1 - use `jdupes -B` just like with BTRFS/XFS on Linux. https://github.com/jbruchon/jdupes/releases

Answer (score 5):

Check out diskDedupe http://www.diskdedupe.com 
It does exactly what you are looking for.

It just has two buttons (scan and deduplicate) and maintains all metadata, when replacing a duplicate with a clone of the the original.

I used it on all my archives.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  What's your experience using this software?  You appear to have just joined this site today so we'd like to know why you're recommending this specific software?

Comment: Hi fsb, I have waited for APFS since Apple decided to write their own file system APFS, instead of using ZFS. Then I was disappointed that APFS does not provide any deduplication functionality like ZFS does. Therefore I was searching for a simple app that provides at least some offline deduplication. I found diskDedupe via Google search for APFS and deduplication and tried it out. I also found the this page and wanted to share my experience. I use diskDedupe for more than 4 months now, it is not expensive and it saved me a lot of disk space.

Comment: Thanks both @fsb for being skeptical and scrutinizing claims and also peter1999 for then clearly stating your motives & use-cases which seem plausible and believable.

Answer (score 4):

There are some alpha-quality open source scripts that try to do this - https://github.com/ranvel/clonefile-dedup

Comment: Yeah, I found this one too. Unfortunately there are a couple of reasons I don't find it usable: ultimately, it is just using `cp -c`, which discards all the metadata of the origin file (owner, permission, extended attributes, etc.). And there's no reason it couldn't just be done with a shell script, calling `sqlite3` directly—instead, you have to install Python 3, which means its off-limits to non-admins who can't change settings to run unsigned/non-App-Store signed code.

Comment: I submitted some changes (and they were approved) to
https://github.com/ranvel/clonefile-dedup Now it will preserve file date and time, as well as chown/chmod attributes.

Answer (score 2):

See also https://github.com/deckarep/apfs-compactor, which is also just a prototype.